# showing updated items from two lists in different site.?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, data-view-web-part

I have two lists in top level site, I have used DataView to show all items from the all two lists order by modify.
Of course, this DataView webpart showing data but not in proper way. 
I'm looking to show the items as same as items in the list (can see each item in a window by clicking on that item, can modify any field in the item).

Appreciate if any suggestions..

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataView is not quite suitable solution to show information from two lists, because it basically makes CAML query to the list.

You can implement your requirement using Search. You can use Search Query Web Part.

You can look here
https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a?CorrelationId=8e718c3d-ae5d-43d0-becd-374be3c3e747&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679900(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thank you ECM4D, sorry for my late reply. Is this possible to accomplish by dashboard because i want to show status column from workflow. this status column is from workflow (depends on different groups approvals).

Comment: You should check if your workflow columns are crawled in the Search Schema of Search Service application or Site Collection (actually, I have never tried to search by workflow status columns myself). If yes, you can create one search managed column and map it to both of your workflow status columns. Them you should successfully write search query using this managed property. Here is more information how to manage search schema https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx#proc1